# Почему функция не возвращает данные?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код:

```
function CreateArrayOfAltName(bezraz) {
    var altnames = new Array();
    $.get("getaltname.php", {
        "serid": $("#serA option:selected").val(),
        "typeid": $("#typeA option:selected").val()
    }, function (data) {
        altnames[0] = data;
        $.get("getaltname.php", {
            "serid": $("#cabeltype option:selected").val(),
            "typeid": 0
        }, function (data) {
            altnames[1] = data;
            if (!bezraz) $.get("getaltname.php", {
                "serid": $("#serB option:selected").val(),
                "typeid": $("#typeB option:selected").val()
            }, function (data) {
                altnames[2] = data;
                return (altnames);
            });
            else return (altnames);
        });
    });
};
```

Он соответственно должен вернуть мне массив. Но почему-то не возвращает, хотя если использовать `alert(altnames);` то данные я вижу. Что делать? И второй вопрос: это быдлокод? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том что вы не там его возвращаете, вы массив возвращаете в callback-функции, а надо в `CreateArrayOfAltName`.

Вот так должен выглядеть код:

```
function CreateArrayOfAltName(bezraz) {
    var altnames = new Array();
    $.get("getaltname.php", {
        "serid": $("#serA option:selected").val(),
        "typeid": $("#typeA option:selected").val()
    }, function(data) {
        altnames[0] = data;
        $.get("getaltname.php", {
            "serid": $("#cabeltype option:selected").val(),
            "typeid": 0
        }, function(data) {
            altnames[1] = data;
            if (!bezraz) 
            { 
                $.get("getaltname.php", {
                    "serid": $("#serB option:selected").val(),
                    "typeid": $("#typeB option:selected").val()
                }, function(data) {
                       altnames[2] = data;
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return altnames;
};
```

Что касается второго вопроса - да, есть немного :), попробуйте вынести параметры get запросов в переменные это уменьшит код с основной логикой и не будет отвлекать от сути.

Answer (score 0):

Начну со второго)) - Да, это быдлокод:)
Где скобки после if(!bezraz)? По идее они должны решить проблему.

```
if (!bezraz){
    $.get("getaltname.php", {
                "serid": $("#serB option:selected").val(),
                "typeid": $("#typeB option:selected").val()
            }, function (data) {
                altnames[2] = data;
                return (altnames);
            });
}
else return (altnames);
```

Comment: Скобки здесь не помогут, в if/while/for... можно опустить скобки если тело if/цикла состоит из одного операнда (я знаю про оператор запятая :) ). Но без них код сливается в кучу :)